# htaccess mod_rewrite RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having difficulties to get this to work. Maybe someone can help me.

If a user opens

> domain.com/folder/images/1.png

the server should rewrite to

> domain.com/folder/images/image.php?file=1.png

since some rewrites are required elswhere on the site, I thought I should put the .htaccess file for this one into

> domain.com/folder/images/

containing

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([\.\-_0-9A-Za-z]+)$ image.php?file=$1 [L]
```

but this somehow sets

> $1=image.php

instead of using the actual filename. If I use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([\-_0-9A-Za-z]+)$ image.php?file=$1 [L]
```

the redirect only works for strings without a period in it

If i can get the behavior for multiple folders with one single .htacces file in the root of domain.com it would be even better. Oh and btw, the file extension can only be jpg or png. Can i include that into the regular expression?
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your root htaccess (or better in you vhost conf file and disable AllowOverride, to disable the use of htaccess)

```
RewriteRule ^folder/images/([\.\-_0-9a-z]+)$ folder/images/image.php?file=$1 [L,N]
```

N for case insensitive url.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! It opens the right file but the value that i read with $_GET is image.php and I don't know why. Is there a way to also check for png or jpg as the file's extension?